# Number of roots of a separable polynomial over a connected ring does not exceed deg $f$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, roots, ideals, polynomial-rings

Let $R$ be a connected ring (i.e. $X^2 - X$ has exactly two roots), and $f ∈ R[X]$ a separable polynomial:

$$ R[X] = R[X]f + R[X]f'.$$

Let $a,b ∈ R$ be roots of $f$, and $g ∈ R[X]$ be such that $f = (X-a)g$.

**To demonstrate:** $f$ has at most deg $f$ roots.

I've already proven that in connected rings, we have for ideals $I, J \trianglelefteq R$: 
$$(IJ = \{0\} \wedge I+J = R) \Rightarrow \{I,J\} = \{\{0\}, R\}.
$$

I've also shown that the ideals $I := R· (b-a), J := R· g(b)$ satisfy the property $IJ = \{0\} \wedge I+J = R$. This leads us to two cases: I) $R(b-a) = \{0\} \wedge Rg(b) = R$; II) $R(b-a) = R \wedge Rg(b) = \{0\}.$

**Case I.** 
We have $b-a=0$, so $b=a$. Note that $f ≠ 0$. If deg$f = 0$, $f$ has no roots, which contradicts $a,b$ being roots. Hence $f$ is not constant: deg$f ≥ 1$. Because $a,b$ were arbitrary roots, and they are equal, $f$ has only 1 root, and we are also done.

**Case II.**
We know that $b≠a$, because $b-a \in R^* \subseteq R \setminus \{0\}$. This is were I get stuck. I haven't tried an induction proof yet (I tend to avoid those), but maybe that is the only way.

**Edit**

I can't even do it for the base case. This is the case deg$f = 2$, because we have, by assumption, two distinct roots. Then deg $g = 1$, so we can write $g = g_1X + g_0$. As $g(b) = 0$, we find $g_1b = -g_0$. Suppose there exists a third root $c$. Then we have: 
$$ 0 = f(c) = (c-a)g(c) = (c-a)(g_1c+g_0) = g_1(c-a)(c-b).
$$
This should give a contradiction, but I don't see it.

Comment: Try an induction, this is the way to go as in the case where $R$ is an integral domain. I don't see what else you would want to do. What do you have to prove to make the induction work?

(Note: I find funny that in the cases I and II, we can use both sides of the conjunction, they really say the same thing.)

Comment: Most of your discussion doesn't really make sense--the statement you are trying to prove has nothing to do with $a$ and $b$, so nothing you prove by just considering $a$ and $b$ is going to solve the problem.  In particular, your conclusion in Case I is just wrong--$a$ and $b$ are _not_ arbitrary roots but are instead two particular roots that were fixed at the start.  Presumably what you want to show is that _any_ root of $f$ is either equal to $a$ or a root of $g$, so you can then use induction on degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be getting badly confused about the role of $a$ and $b$ in this argument.  The first thing to understand is that this entire business with $a$ and $b$ is not an argument to solve the problem on its own, but is rather supposed to be embedded inside an induction proof.  In particular, the goal is *not* to prove directly that $f$ has at most $\deg f$ roots in each case, but instead to reach a different conclusion which supports the induction step of the proof.

Here's the correct setup for the proof.  We prove by induction on $\deg f$ that if $f$ is a separable polynomial over $R$, then $f$ has at most $n$ roots (note that $a$ and $b$ are not part of the statement at all yet, and will only be introduced later).  The base case is $\deg f=0$, in which case trivially $f$ cannot have any roots since it is a nonzero constant polynomial.

Now suppose $\deg f>0$ and the result is already known for polynomials of smaller degree.  If $f$ has no roots we are done; otherwise, let $a$ be some root of $f$.  We can then factor $f(X)=(X-a)g(X)$ for some polynomial $g$.  Then $g$ is also separable (proof left as an exercise), and so by the induction hypothesis it has at most $\deg g=\deg f-1$ roots.  If we can show that every root of $f$ is either equal to $a$ or a root of $g$, we can then conclude that $f$ has at most $\deg f$ roots.

So here's where $b$ comes in: we let $b$ be an arbitrary root of $f$, and our goal now is to prove that either $b=a$ or $b$ is a root of $g$.  Now the cases you consider finally come in handy: in Case I we have $b-a=0$ and so $b=a$, and in Case II we have $g(b)=0$ and so $b$ is a root of $g$.